# NativeMessageHandler+<SendAsync> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-app-center

We have developed an application in Xamarin iOS and Android.

We have used Azure services and AppCenter for crash log reporting.

For Android, We have received a huge number of below logs

```
ModernHttpClient
NativeMessageHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext ()
System.Net.Http
HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>d__49.MoveNext ()
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices
MobileServiceHttpClient+<SendRequestAsync>d__1d.MoveNext ()
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices
MobileServiceHttpClient+<RequestAsync>d__4.MoveNext ()
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices
MobileServiceClient+<InternalInvokeApiAsync>d__b.MoveNext ()
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices
MobileServiceClient+<InvokeApiAsync>d__6.MoveNext ()
```

I have tried to search it but not able to find out why this is getting logged,

Error log information is as below :

```
NativeMessageHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext ()
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
O
```

Any help or idea how to debug this error log in deeper will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Any success with this? @Wolverine

Answer (score 0):

MS App Center gives you the report for each crash. You can check out from 14:40 of [this MSDN video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Monitor-Your-Apps-Health-with-App-Center-Analytics--Crash) to how see the details that are provided. They even allow you to record the username of the person having the crash now.

So, if you implement Analytics events like shown below, you could figure out exactly how to replicate the error and place an exception catch-point.

```
Analytics.TrackEvent("PageView: LoginPage");
```

```
Analytics.TrackEvent("SelectAction: LoginButton");
```

It seems to be related to asynchronous programming from what I see in the HTTPClient layer (from MoveNext). I would suggest making the following changes in your code to ensure that it follows [best practices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=My2gAv5Vrkk) shown on by Microsoft's Brandon Minnick. You could also share some of the web service layer code to help us more